# Eclipse Maven Plugin fails to create groovy-maven-archetype project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, groovy, plexus

I have installed the Maven for Eclipse plugin from Sonatype.

(update site: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update/)

I am creating a Maven project, and choosing to use the `groovy-maven-archetype` as my starting point.

However, halfway through, I am seeing:

```
04/03/09 12:52:28 GMT: [FATAL ERROR] 
org.codehaus.mojo.groovy.stubgen.GenerateStubsMojo#execute()
caused a linkage error (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError). Check the realms:

... snip ...

Realm ID: plexus.core

org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer.createChildContainer
(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Map;)
Lorg/codehaus/plexus/PlexusContainer;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you can use gmaven-archetype-basic v1.0-rc-5 with eclipse 3.4. That correctly creates groovy maven project for eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

At a command prompt, enter this:  `mvn archetype:generate`
Then, choose `40` (gmaven-archetype-basic)
Then, follow the prompts.
Once you have a maven project, you can enable [Eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) support by saying:  `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

You can read [Building Groovy Projects](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Building+Groovy+Projects) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a versioning problem to me. Are you sure you used all the right versions of the jars?

Comment: Yeah, looks like an installation problem for me too. Try to reinstall m2eclipse. If that doesn't help, you get possibly better help at the m2eclipse users mailing list: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/project-information.html

Answer (score 0):

Getting Groovy-Eclipse, gmaven, and Eclipse all working together seems to be pretty tricky at the present. Once you've got a project created with `mvn archetype:generate`, as AWhitford mentions, [this site](http://contraptionsforprogramming.blogspot.com/2009/12/getting-gmaven-to-play-nicely-with.html) will show you a few of the tweaks you'll need to make it work.

GMaven's stub creation for Java files interferes with Groovy-Eclipse, hence the section on that page about commenting out stub creation. However, I went with the method mentioned in the comments for the relevant bug ([GMAVEN-61](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GMAVEN-61)) and created multiple executions for the gmaven plugin, like so:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-rc-3</version>
        <!-- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GMAVEN-61 -->
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stubsonly</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generateStubs</goal>
              <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

I'm still not certain myself that this is clean for both pure Maven usage as well as within Eclipse, but it at least got me to the point where I stopped spending hours trying to get anything to work and got me coding on my actual project.

The [Groovy-Eclipse](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin) and [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Building+Groovy+Projects) documentation are good reading for background info.